# Convert list to int and sum all elements in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

Very new to pandas and I'm trying to sum the elements of a list in a single column for a pandas dataframe, except I can't find a way to do so

The dataframe looks something like this:

```
index codes 
0     [19, 19]
1     [3, 4]
2     [20, 5, 3]
3     NaN
4     [1]
5     NaN
6     [14, 2]
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
index codes       total 
0     [19, 19]    38
1     [3, 4]      7 
2     [20, 5, 3]  28
3     NaN         0 
4     [1]         1
5     NaN         0
6     [14, 2]     16
```

However the values in codes were obtained by using `str.findall('-(\d+)')` from a different column, so they are not a list of ints

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `str.extractall()` instead of `str.findall()`:

```
# replace orig_column with the correct column name
df['total'] = (df['orig_column'].str.extractall('-(\d+)')
                 .astype(int).sum(level=0)
                 .reindex(df.index, fill_value=0)
              )
```

If you really want to use your current `codes` column:

```
df['total'] = df['codes'].explode().astype(float).sum(level=0)
```

Output:

```
   index       codes  total
0      0    [19, 19]     38
1      1      [3, 4]      7
2      2  [20, 5, 3]     28
3      3         NaN      0
4      4         [1]      1
5      5         NaN      0
6      6     [14, 2]     16
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I spent over an hour looking over answers for summing numbers within a pandas string column, and this was the first one that actually worked

Answer (score 1):

Try `df['total'] = df['codes'].apply(lambda x:int(np.nansum(x)))` if you want int type output.

Try `df['total'] = df['codes'].apply(lambda x:np.nansum(x))` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['total'] = (
    df.codes.apply(lambda x: sum([int(e) for e in x]) if type(x) == list else 0)
)
```